# Extract comman command from DockerFiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have a couple of DockerFiles that runs the same command
`COPY --from=/source /dest`

Since we will change the `/source` from time to time, is it possible to extract this into some common util file and use it everywhere?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example of where this comes up, and why repeating that one line is a problem?  It's possible to run multiple containers off of the same image and to override the command when you run them, which could address some potential use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass it as an [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to `docker build`.

```
docker build --build-arg mysourcedir=/source Dockerfile
```

and in the Dockerfile

```
# use /source as default if no arg is supplied
ARG mysourcedir=/source

...
COPY --from=$mysourcedir /dest
...
```

Or if you use docker compose then you could put this as an environment variable into a `.env` file and pass it with the `--env-file` flag. Details can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).